# HP-UX: libstd_v2 in stack trace of JNI code compiled with g++

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, java-native-interface, hp-ux

uname -mr: B.11.23 ia64

g++ --version: g++ (GCC) 4.4.0

java -version:

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0.06-jinteg_20_jan_2010_05_50-b00)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 14.3-b01-jre1.6.0.06-rc1, mixed mode)

I'm trying to run a Java application that uses JNI. It is crashing inside the JNI code with the following (abbreviated) stack trace:

```
(0) 0xc0000000249353e0 VMError::report_and_die{_ZN7VMError14report_and_dieEv} + 0x440 at /CLO/Components/JAVA_HOTSPOT/Src/src/share/vm/utilities/vmError.cpp:738 [/opt/java6/jre/lib/IA64W/server/libjvm.so]
(1) 0xc000000024559240 os::Hpux::JVM_handle_hpux_signal{_ZN2os4Hpux22JVM_handle_hpux_signalEiP9
__siginfoPvi} + 0x760 at /CLO/Components/JAVA_HOTSPOT/Src/src/os_cpu/hp-ux_ia64/vm/os_hp-ux_ia64.cpp:1051 [/opt/java6/jre/lib/IA64W/server/libjvm.so]
(2) 0xc0000000245331c0 os::Hpux::signalHandler{_ZN2os4Hpux13signalHandlerEiP9__siginfoPv} + 0x80 at /CLO/Components/JAVA_HOTSPOT/Src/src/os/hp-ux/vm/os_hp-ux.cpp:4295 [/opt/java6/jre/lib/IA64W/server/libjvm.so]
(3) 0xe00000010e002620 ---- Signal 11 (SIGSEGV) delivered ----
(4) 0xc0000000000d2d20 __pthread_mutex_lock + 0x400 at /ux/core/libs/threadslibs/src/common/pthreads/mutex.c:3895 [/usr/lib/hpux64/libpthread.so.1]
(5) 0xc000000000342e90 __thread_mutex_lock + 0xb0 at ../../../../../core/libs/libc/shared_em_64/../core/threads/wrappers1.c:273 [/usr/lib/hpux64/libc.so.1]
(6) 0xc00000000177dff0 _HPMutexWrapper::lock{_ZN15_HPMutexWrapper4lockEPv} + 0x90 [/usr/lib/hpux64/libstd_v2.so.1]
(7) 0xc0000000017e9960 std::basic_string,std::allocator{_ZNSsC1ERKSs} + 0x80 [/usr/lib/hpux64/libstd_v2.so.1]
(8) 0xc000000008fd9fe0 JniString::str{_ZNK9JniString3strEv} + 0x50 at eg_handler_jni.cxx:50 [/soft/bus-7_0/lib/libbus_registry_jni.so.7.0.0]
(9) 0xc000000008fd7060 pt_efacec_se_aut_frk_cmp_registry_REGHandler::getKey{_ZN44pt_efacec_se_aut_frk_cmp_registry_REGHandler6getKeyEP8_jstringi} + 0xa0 [/soft/bus-7_0/lib/libbus_registry_jni.so.7.0.0]
(10) 0xc000000008fd17f0 Java_pt_efacec_se_aut_frk_cmp_registry_REGHandler_getKey__Ljava_lang_String_2I + 0xa0 [/soft/bus-7_0/lib/libbus_registry_jni.so.7.0.0]
(11) 0x9fffffffdf400ed0

Internal error (-3) while unwinding stack [/CLO/Components/JAVA_HOTSPOT/Src/src/os_cpu/hp-ux_ia64/vm/thread_hp-ux_ia64.cpp:142]
```

This JNI code and dependencies are being compiled using g++, are multithreaded and 64 bit (-pthread -mlp64 -shared -fPIC). The LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable is set the dependencies location, and running ldd on the JNI shared libraries finds them all:

ldd libbus_registry_jni.so:

```
libefa-d.so.7 => /soft/bus-7_0/lib/libefa-d.so.7
libbus_registry-d.so.7 => /soft/bus-7_0/lib/libbus_registry-d.so.7
libboost_thread-gcc44-mt-d-1_41.so => /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread-gcc44-mt-d-1_41.so
libboost_system-gcc44-mt-d-1_41.so => /usr/local/lib/libboost_system-gcc44-mt-d-1_41.so
libboost_regex-gcc44-mt-d-1_41.so => /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex-gcc44-mt-d-1_41.so
librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/hpux64/librt.so.1
libstdc++.so.6 => /opt/hp-gcc-4.4.0/lib/gcc/ia64-hp-hpux11.23/4.4.0/../../../hpux64/libstdc++.so.6
libm.so.1 => /usr/lib/hpux64/libm.so.1
libgcc_s.so.0 => /opt/hp-gcc-4.4.0/lib/gcc/ia64-hp-hpux11.23/4.4.0/../../../hpux64/libgcc_s.so.0
libunwind.so.1 => /usr/lib/hpux64/libunwind.so.1
librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/hpux64/librt.so.1
libm.so.1 => /usr/lib/hpux64/libm.so.1
libunwind.so.1 => /usr/lib/hpux64/libunwind.so.1
libdl.so.1 => /usr/lib/hpux64/libdl.so.1
libunwind.so.1 => /usr/lib/hpux64/libunwind.so.1
libc.so.1 => /usr/lib/hpux64/libc.so.1
libuca.so.1 => /usr/lib/hpux64/libuca.so.1
```

Looking at the stack trace, it seams odd that, although ldd list g++'s libstdc++ is being used, the std:string copy c'tor being reported as used is the one in libstd_v2, the implementation provided by aCC.

The crash happens in the following code, when method str() returns:

```
class JniString {
std::string m_utf8;

public:
JniString(JNIEnv* env, jstring instance) {
const char* utf8Chars = env->GetStringUTFChars(instance, 0);
if (utf8Chars == 0) {
env->ExceptionClear(); // RPF
throw std::runtime_error("GetStringUTFChars returned 0");
}
m_utf8.assign(utf8Chars);
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(instance, utf8Chars);
}

std::string str() const {
return m_utf8;
}
};
```

Simultaneous usage of the two C++ implementations could likely be a reason for the crash, but that should not be happening.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is probably a good idea to ask about HP-UX on their site [HP-UX](http://forums11.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/familyhome.do?familyId=117).

As for this crash you can try usual steps like installing latest patches for HP libraries libpthread.so and libunwind.so.

If the crash is in one of POSIX threads it might be of help to make sure that your POSIX threads have enough stack space. One way of doing it is (if you have the latest libpthread):

```
# up to 10 Mb you can set as far as I remember
# here I set arounf 2Mb for each POSIX thread
# it works if you do not set your own stack size for threads
export PTHREAD_DEFAULT_STACK_SIZE=2000000
./your_application
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a project that use jni on IA64, below script will compile 'libosapij.so.0'. The  aCC compilation options may help:

$ cat make.sh

```
export CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH;
TGT="libosapij.so"
CXX="aCC +DD64 +eh -ext -AA -mt -b"

rm -f com_hp_os_OSAPI.h;
rm -f $TGT;
rm -f com/hp/os/OSAPI.class;
rm -f com/hp/os/TestApp.class;

$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac com/hp/os/OSAPI.java;
$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac com/hp/os/TestApp.java;
$JAVA_HOME/bin/javah -jni com.hp.os.OSAPI;

SRC="com_hp_os_OSAPI.cc";
INC="-I$JAVA_HOME/include -I$JAVA_HOME/include/hp-ux -I../APP/include";
MY_LIBS="../APP/lib/libosapi.a";
OS_LIBS="-L./ -lrwtool_v2 -lstd_v2 -lm";

echo "$CXX -o $TGT $SRC $INC $MY_LIBS $OS_LIBS";
$CXX -o $TGT $SRC $INC $MY_LIBS $OS_LIBS
echo "cp $TGT $TGT.0";
cp $TGT $TGT.0

echo "unit test"
echo "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -d64 -Djava.library.path=./  com.hp.os.TestApp"
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -d64 -Djava.library.path=./  com.hp.os.TestApp
echo "Done!"
```